# Unsure why method is spitting out what its spitting out

Tags: javascript, object, methods, constructor, prototype

This seems like such a dumb question but...
If we have a constructor:

```
function Candy(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

and we extend the prototype of this object Candy:

```
Candy.prototype.printName = function(name) {
    console.log(this.name);
};
```

then we create a new object from the Candy constructor and run the inherited method for this new object:

```
var chocolate = new Candy("chocolate");
chocolate.printName();
```

It's not clicking with me as to why we get chocolate as an output.
When we create the chocolate object from the constructor have we in essence done this:

```
var chocolate = new Candy();
chocolate.name = name;
```

and if so, why is it that when we run:

```
chocolate.printName();
```

with a blank argument, it spits out: "chocolate"?
Isn't chocolate simply the name of the object that we built out of the Candy construcor?
As in, chocolate is not what we have assigned the chocolate.name parameter to be, but name is. Since we passed an empty argument field, why are we getting "chocolate" and not name back?

Comment: Why passing parameter to `printName` matters here? you have not used the value of the passed argument inside `printName`. Also, what is the value of the `name` when you assign it to `chocolate.name`?

Comment: Because you're extending the parent object and not overriding its class variable. The class variable will therefore still be accessible in the extended scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `name` in the `printName` method is never used. To call the method with the signature that you specified, you would do like this:

```
chocolate.printName("Fudge");
```

That would send the string `"Fudge"` into the method as the parameter `name`, but the parameter is ignored, and it still prints out the name that you specified for the object instead.

Javascript allows you to call any function with any number of parameters. If you use too few parameters, the rest of the parameters will just have the value `undefined`, and if you use too many parameters, they will be in the `arguments` collection, but they will not be put in a parameter variable.

So, if you call `chocolate.printName();`, the parameter `name` will have the value `undefined`. If you call `chocolate.printName(1,2,3)`, parameter `name` will have the value `1`, and the other values would be available inside the function as `arguments[1]` and `arguments[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you are looking for, but if you add the following `prototype` function

```
Candy.prototype.compare = function (obj) {
  console.log(this === obj);
}

var chocolate = new Candy();
```

And call it,

```
chocolate.compare(chocolate);
```

It will print true. So, when you assign the value

```
chocolate.name = name; // Asuming name = 'chocolate'
```

`chocolate.printName();` will always print the value of `name`, i.e. chocolate

Answer (score 0):

Because you do this:

```
var chocolate = new Candy("chocolate"); // "chocolate" is your argument here
```

And inside your Candy constructor, the argument is taken and assigned to `this.name`...

```
function Candy(name) {
   this.name = name; // name is "chocolate" if we use the above
}
```

Then the `printname` method will just return "chocolate" since it's just logging `this.name` from within the Candy object, which you defined as whatever argument is passed to the `Candy()` constructor.

Hope that makes sense.